# Does system.net connectionManagement only apply to web traffic?

Tags: .net

I can't find any clear answer on this.  The MSDN documentation does not specify what types of connections it limits, but all of the examples show http traffic.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb6y0fyc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

It seems to imply if I use a wildcard '*', it applies to all connections.  Does that include, e.g. SQL server?

Answer (score 0):

No, [the doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6484zdc1(v=vs.110).aspx) states:

> Specifies the maximum number of connections to an Internet host

UPDATE

On the same doc page, in the **Remarks** section they state:

> The  Element (Network Settings) element contains settings for classes in the System.Net and related child namespaces. The settings configure authentication modules, connection management, mail settings, the proxy server, and Internet request modules for receiving information from Internet hosts.

Comment: That's the part that seems vague to me.  Any public-facing service on the Internet is an "Internet host".  It could be FTP, IRC, Gopher, SQL, etc.  It does not specifically say "web host".

Comment: I agree is not the most precise piece of documentation on MSDN, still I think it's clear this does not apply to SQL Servers. See my update, I think this is particularly clear: `in the System.Net and related child namespaces`.